# Identify this animated series with the animal fighters which transforms

Tags: animation, identify-this-tv-show

Approximately 7-8 year before I have seen a cartoon series where animals fight with their enemy using super natural powers. The main enemy in the series is a self minded machine which sends mechanical robot fighter each time to fight with the animal group.

Animals group have a leader who looks like King Kong with his friends which are bat, spider, etc. The all animals can transform into different looks with more powers. It's somehow inspired from Transformers animated series in background music and transformation sequence.

In the middle of series the animal won and they killed the machines but the main machine became a virus and controlled the mind of animals to make fight in between them.

Can somebody identify this animated series which was telecast on Cartoon Network India more than 6-7 years ago?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [Beast Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_Beast_Wars) which was a *Transformers* series where the Transformers were animals instead of vehicles.

The initial US run 1997-1999 so I'm not sure about the Indian run as the wiki only lists actors for US, Japan, and Spanish.

It featured the battle between the *Maximals* (Autobots) and the *Predecons* (Decepticons) with mostly the same names as the primary transformers with animal puns (e.g. Optimus *Primal*).

Followed by the direct sequel [Beast Machines: Transformers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beast_Machines:_Transformers).

Comment: Finally i got to review it and my answer is [Beast Machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beast_Machines). Which is sequel of  Beast Wars, still making it rite answer.